# How to use an array to work around google scripts "service invoked too many times for one day" error

Tags: arrays, google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a simple script to fetch the distance between two locations, each in a different cell in GoogleSheets (below). My sheet has one set of 65 locations in the top row and a second set of 6000 locations listed in the first column. I want to find the distance between each location in the top row and each location in the first column.

Given the size of my data set, I'm running into the "service invoked too many times for one day: route" error message. I found [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47537/how-to-avoid-invoked-too-many-times-per-second-error) suggesting that one could create an array to execute calculations for the whole spreadsheet at once, rather than cell by cell. Would this be a suitable solution for my current problem? If so, how would I go about writing the script? Here's my current code:

```
function GOOGLEMAPS(start_address,end_address) {

    Utilities.sleep(1000)


  var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
  mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

 var meters = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["value"];
 var distance = meters * 0.000621371

 //Logger.log(distance)

 return distance;

}
```

Comment: The query limits are the query limits.  6000 x 65 is going to count as abuse unless you spread it over a really long time period (there are no provisions for bulk geocoding with the Google APIs).

Answer (score 0):

If you desire overcome a daily limit established by the Google Apps Script you should initialize a Map with the Google Maps Premium plan credentials. This means you should contact Google and purchase a Google Maps Platform Premium plan license in order to get additional quota allowances.

There is a `Maps.setAuthentication(clientId, signingKey);` method for this purpose.

> Enables the use of an externally established Maps API for Business account, to leverage additional quota allowances. Your client ID and signing key can be obtained from the Google Enterprise Support Portal. Set these values to null to go back to using the default quota allowances.

source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps#setAuthentication(String,String)

I hope this answer clarifies your doubt.